# Add to a multidimensional array from a loop

Tags: java, arrays, list, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I am not so proficient in Java, and I will appreciate if someone could help me to figure out the problem that I have.

So here is my piece of code:`

```
       static void sum_up_recursive(ArrayList<Double> numbers, int target, ArrayList<Double> partial) {
       double s = 0;
       for (double x: partial) s += x;
       if ( s <target )   

           System.out.println("sum("+Arrays.toString(partial.toArray())+ " " +partial.size() +")="+target);

           if (s >= target)
            return;`
```

and it gives me this result

```
 sum([1.3, 0.5, 0.5, 1.3, 0.5, 1.3, 1.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5] 10)<=12
 sum([1.3, 0.5, 0.5, 1.3, 0.5, 1.3, 1.3, 0.5, 1.3] 9)<=12
 sum([1.3, 0.5, 0.5, 1.3, 0.5, 1.3, 1.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5] 10)<=12
 sum([1.3, 0.5, 0.5, 1.3, 0.5, 1.3, 1.3, 0.5, 1.3] 9)<=12
 sum([1.3, 0.5, 0.5, 1.3, 0.5, 1.3, 1.3, 0.5, 1.3, 0.5] 10)<=12
 sum([1.3, 0.5, 0.5, 1.3, 0.5, 1.3, 1.3, 0.5, 1.3, 0.5, 1.3] 11)<=12
 and so on... There are hundreds if it..
```

What I'd like to do, is to store all these result in a multi-array to manipulate them more easy or maybe you know how to sort them in that loop. Like choosing one of rows which has the sum of elements bigger.

Thank you

Comment: So you just want to store the result of summing all them up in a `global` array?

Comment: I want to sum all the elements in each row displayed me in the console and afterward to compare each sum to find out which one is bigger. I specifically want to know which one are closer to 12. thx

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class holding both the `List` and the sum :

```
class Sum {

    ArrayList<Double> numbers;
    Double total;
}
```

and a custom `Comparator` for this class

```
class SumComparator implements Comparator<Pair> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Sum a, Sum b) {
        return Double.compare(a.total, b.total);
    }
}
```

Then you can sort an array of Pair like this :

```
Sum[] sums = new Sum[]; // initialize with values
Arrays.sort(sums, new SumComparator());
```

This will sort an array or Sum according to the sum of each `List` of numbers in each `Sum` object.